# Reveal something in third person limited

Tags: third-person

My character is wondering why the Minotaur King is trying to hunt him.

I want to reveal to my readers that the MC's parents were paid Minotaur slayers and had killed the Minotaur princes, without the MC figuring that out, and both parents are seemingly dead.

How can I express this to my readers?

Comment: How important is it for the reader to understand the reason? Would dropping hints be acceptable that would allow the more observant readers to make the connection? The rest could find out much later along with the MC.

Comment: @Llewellyn, I think that I would put subtle hints in dialogue and diaries, but I think that would mean that only the more observant readers can enjoy the book, because otherwise the book just will seem like it is about pointless action rather than a storyline to readers who are just "skimming" the book.

Comment: Are you setting up a **mystery** (a minotaur conspiracy erased the truth), a **plot twist** (Luke, I am your father), or a **coming-of-age story** (MarySue Potter was the saddest orphan ever until she learned what literally every other character in this universe already knows but didn't bother to tell her)...? Each has different *narrative setups*, *worldbuilding clues*, and *protagonist blindspots*.

Comment: I think the first option is what I'm trying to set up. The Minotaurs have implanted a fake story that the Minotaur Princes were slain by "vicious horned groundhogs" (so that they don't directly accuse humanity, and humanity is much more powerful in terms of military and skill), and only the topmost people (general, king, etc...) know about what really happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two techniques open to you.

The first is to have the character relate the facts, but not make the obvious conclusion.

> In March of '22, my parents were in Calcutta. That was the same time that Prince Graze was murdered.  And in '02 they were in four other cities were Minotaur Princes were assassinated.  I missed them, but when they come home, they always had lots more money and brought me presents.

The second is to share the facts through narrative. The narrator of the story knows everything -- except the thought of the non-POV characters.

> Jack had been a baby when his parents took the contracts for the hides of the 9 Minotaur Princes of Amber. By the time Jack started to wonder what he parents did for a living, they'd given up that life, even though they'd been very successful and opened a florist shop.  To Jack, his parents were florists, despite their terrible allergies.